In dev server I have downloaded Jenkins but using my port number and Ip address I am unable to open in web page by this port number and Ip address
In dev server I have downloaded Jenkins but using my port number and Ip address I am unable to open in web page by this port number and Ip address. What should I change? I am using Linux. I am getting web page as http://XXXXXXXXX/This site can’t be reachedXXXXXXX took too long to respond.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
In firewall Inbound I add New rule Port number by TCP. In dev server I have downloaded Jenkins but using my port number and Ip address I am unable to open in web page by this port number and Ip address.
